# Return List contains Integer rather than expected type, using Room Entity

Tags: java, android, android-room

In using Room, I'm getting a ClassCastException in code traversing a List that should be holding objects of the expected type. Please see the "FIXME" comment in code attached.

I've tried using `Person` and `PersonEntity` rather than `? extends Person`, but there is no change in result.

Based on Room examples, I am using a repository as mediator between the DAO and ViewModel. A separate thread is used to insert group information and members.

Stack trace from exception:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>       Process: myproject, PID: 7323
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
>           at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:318)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>           at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
>        Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to myproject.model.Person
>           at myproject.persist.Repository$insertGroupTask.doInBackground(Repository.java:609)
>           at myproject.persist.Repository$insertGroupTask.doInBackground(Repository.java:583)
>           at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)

This class is in the repository class

```
private static class insertGroupTask extends AsyncTask<GroupEntity, Void, Void>
{
    private GroupDAO mAsyncTaskDao;

    insertGroupTask(GroupDAO dao) {
        mAsyncTaskDao = dao;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground (final GroupEntity... params)
    {
        mAsyncTaskDao.insert(params[0]);
        // Add group members.
        List<? extends Person> members = params[0].getMembers();
        if (members == null || members.size() == 0)
            return null;

        // FIXME: A ClassCastException occurs (Integer instead of Person).
        for (Person p : members) // FIXME: How can members be a list containing Integer objects? See getMembers() in GroupEntity
        {
            mAsyncTaskDao.addGroupMember(params[0].getId(), p.getId());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Classes below are outside the repository definition.

```
@Dao
public abstract class GroupDAO implements BaseDAO<GroupEntity>
{
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    abstract void addGroupMember (GroupMemberEntity member);

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    public void addGroupMember (int idGroup, int idPerson)
    {
        // GroupMemberEntity caters for the m:n association of Group and Person, using the id of each
        GroupMemberEntity grp = new GroupMemberEntity(idGroup, idPerson);
        addGroupMember(grp);
    }
}

@Entity(tableName = "groups")
public class GroupEntity implements MutableGroup
{
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "group_id")
    private int id = 0;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Ignore
    private List<? extends Person> m_members;

    @Override
    public List<? extends Person> getMembers ()
    { return m_members; }

    public void setMembers (final List<? extends Person> members)
    { m_members = members; }
}
```

I don't understand how the List is not containing Person objects.

Comment: You might want to edit your question and post the complete stack trace.

Comment: @CommonsWare Done. Line 609 indicated in the stack trace is where I have the "FIXME" comment.

Comment: How is `m_members` getting populated?

Comment: @CommonsWare m_members is populated via a setter method called after the list is extracted from a map<AttributeId, Object>. I've found the problem. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad. I discovered the setter method setMembers(List members) was actually getting a list of member ids (integers) in one use case, where the List is retrieved from a Map.
My new understanding regarding type erasure in generics is that even though the type is defined in the generic for compile, it is treated as "Object" at runtime. So no cast for the List itself could fail. The first type check is when accessing an item in the list (which was relatively long after it was created, in this case).